# Python: IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying to form a list using a specific equation with given parameters, but I keep getting the error that "list index out of range". Here is the section of code:

```
yvalue = [iniPop]
for i in (1,maxIter,1):
    yvalue.append(yvalue[i-1]*(1+(rate*(1-(yvalue[i-1]/CC)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is `range(1, maxIter)` instead of just `(1,maxIter,1)`. So you'll have

```
yvalue = [iniPop]
for i in range(1, maxIter):
    yvalue.append(yvalue[i - 1] * (1 + (rate * (1 - (yvalue[i - 1] / CC)))))
```